# Condition for a cubic polynomial to have two roots with equal imaginary part

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

Given cubic polynomial $a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d = 0$, with potentially complex coefficients, is there a sufficient condition for two of the roots having equal imaginary part?  That is, is there a condition on the coefficients that allows me to guarantee that the roots take the form $s + i t$, $u + i t$, and $v + i w$?

Specifically, I am looking for a condition analogous to the cubic discriminant (i.e. [condition for a cubic to have a repeated root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179417/condition-for-a-cubic-to-have-a-repeated-root)).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Comment: As you said use the discriminant to determine what conditions are needed. What do you mean equal imaginary part? are you saying that they will be of the form $a \pm bi$ or you want $a + bi$ and $c + bi$?

Comment: $a+bi$ and $c+bi$, not to be confused with the coefficients in the cubic.  For instance, if the roots are 6-7i, -17+5i and 3+5i the cubic would qualify.

Comment: For starters, you would have to have at least one coefficient be complex. Aside from that obvious fact, you probably just need to go through the motions of manipulating the discriminant and it will probably be messy.